# How to connect Stripe.com accounts with Stripe.net

Tags: stripe-payments

I am using Stripe.net.  I have a solution where the user will be entering their credit card info in through a website and then I need to transfer $X amount to another Stripe.com account.  How do I connect existing Stripe.com accounts through Connect via Stripe.net or send a transfer to an external Stripe.com account?

Comment: Just to be clear, when you say you're using "stripe.net" you mean the .NET integration for Stripe? https://github.com/stripe/stripe-dotnet

Comment: Yes, that is correct.  I have a MVC.net app that I am trying to integrate Stripe into.